# How to pass functions as args in do.call?

Tags: r, do.call

I try to pass functions as `args` in `do.call`. For example:

```
testF <- function(a,b){

  a(b)

}

ijk <- list(a = c(print, print), b = c(1,2))

do.call(testF, ijk, envir = .GlobalEnv)
#Error in a(b) : could not find function "a"
```

How to fix the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the right way. I think the issue lies in how you define your `a` in the list. Use `function`; also probably `list` is better than `c`.

```
ijk <- list(a=function(x) list(sqrt(x), x^2), b=c(4,9))
do.call(testF, ijk, envir=.GlobalEnv)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 16 81
```